# Codeigniter 4 или другой framework?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Как думаете, стоит ли ждать codeigniter 4 или проще сразу начать изучать какой-то другой framework? Очень нравиться codeigniter из-за своей простоты.

Answer (score 3):

Уже много всего было на эту тему, но вставлю свои 5 копеек. Если уровень начальный, то увеличивайте свои знания без использования фреймворков. Напишите мини-фреймворк для себя. Поймите как все работает и взаимодействует. После этого уже можете перейти на полноценные фреймворки, такие как: Yii, Symfony, Laravel. Попробуйте каждый и сделай выбор для себя. Удачного кодинга...